# Unable to highlight area map

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an area map but I want to highlight the area of the newspaper like border in red color, but I am not getting how to do it .

I am creating the area map as follow :

```
<div>
<img src="http://cantact104.com/wp-content/plugins/eNewsPaper/menu-pages/newspaper/01_17.jpg" id="photo" usemap="#planetmap">
</div>
<map name="planetmap">
<area shape="rect" style="cursor:pointer;" coords="360,6.3,976.5,827.1" target="_blank" onclick="return hello(1);" alt="Sun" onmouseover="borderit(this,'black')" onmouseout="borderit(this,'white')"><area shape="rect" style="cursor:pointer;" coords="0,407.7,667.8,826.2" target="_blank" onclick="return hello(2);" alt="Sun" onmouseover="borderit(this,'black')" onmouseout="borderit(this,'white')"><area shape="rect" style="cursor:pointer;" coords="0,1.8,362.7,404.1" target="_blank" onclick="return hello(3);" alt="Sun" onmouseover="borderit(this,'black')" onmouseout="borderit(this,'white')"><area shape="rect" style="cursor:pointer;" coords="0,826.2,976.5,1543.5" target="_blank" onclick="return hello(4);" alt="Sun" onmouseover="borderit(this,'black')" onmouseout="borderit(this,'white')"></map>
```

function borderit

```
function borderit()
{
alert('dd');
jQuery(this).css("background-color","yellow");
}
</script>
```

Comment: What does your variables contains? How does echoed html looks like?

Comment: And where is the code of your function `borderIt` ?

Comment: added borderit function

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to remove your `borderIt` function and onmouseover/onmouseout attributes because it's complicated to manage with this kind of elements.

Simply use [this great jQuery plugin](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_simple.html), it will be more quick and easy.
(only works with jQuery lte 1.9)

Answer (score 0):

This will add a border to all area with class `bordered`, change to your liking.

```
area.bordered{
    outline:1px solid red;
}
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp for more details.